# Question on higher order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution for $$y''' + 2y'' + 2y' = 0$$

Hi, so I have a question on my work for this higher order ODE.

I took the coefficients and plugged it into the characteristic equation:

$$r^3 + 2r^2 + 2r = 0$$
$$r(r^2 + 2r + 2) = 0$$

Using the quadratic formula, I end up with complex roots:

$$ r = -1 + i, r = -1 - i$$
As well as the real root, $r=0$

Anyways, so this is what I got for the General Solution:

$$y = C_1 + C_2e^{-x}cos(x) + C_3e^{-x}sin(x)$$

I tried checking it, but this ended up becoming terrible. Could someone verify my answer is correct?

Comment: It is.${}{}{}{}$

Comment: I can't see how the checking would becomes terrible... There are three terms and since the equation is linear, you can check term by term.

Comment: Or just ask [Wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(e%5E%7B-x%7D+%5Csin+x)%27%27%27+%2B+2(e%5E%7B-x%7D+%5Csin+x)%27%27+%2B+2(e%5E%7B-x%7D+%5Csin+x)%27+%3D)